# Create template and open in TexStudio (Linux)

Tags: linux, scripts

I am constantly writing up my homework in Latex and they always have the same framework. Is there anyway I can create a script in Linux that creates a file with the framework then opens it in TexStudio?

For example let's say I am in /home/school/ directory and want to create a file named HW3.tex in the same directory with the framework then open it in TexStudio. Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: I suggest to ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com/... Your question has nothing to do with TeX... It is just a linux question.

Comment: Texstudio has a `Make template` entry in the `File` menu that lets you save a file as a template. You can then use that new template to create a new file using `New from template`, also in the `File` menu.

Comment: If you want to roll your own mechanism, you can use Bash script like this: `cp ~/MyTemplate.tex ./MyNewFile.tex; texstudio MyNewFile.tex &`. That assumes that you do indeed have a file `MyTemplate.tex` in your home directory.

Comment: How would I change this so that if I save the bash file as `newtex` I can type `newtex filename.tex` and it'll create a file with that name?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in reply to the question in your comment - it is short, yet doesn't conveniently fit into a single comment.

Create the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

filename=${1%.tex}.tex

template=~/mytemplate.tex

cp $template $filename
texstudio $filename &
```

Save it as `newtex` to some place where your shell can find it. Try:

```
echo $PATH
```

That will return something like

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games ...
```

Saving the file into one of these directories (e.g. /usr/local/bin) will make it visible to the shell. Make it executable with

```
chmod +x newtex
```

Note that copying and chmod-ing will likely require root privilege (that is, the use of `su` or `sudo`).  Now you should be able to invoke the script with

```
newtex myspankingnewfile.tex
```